# Efficiently finding the ranks of elements in an array?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, statistics, performance, space-efficiency

How does one find the rank of each element of an array, averaging in the case of ties, efficiently?  For example:

```
float[] rank(T)(T[] input) {
    // Implementation
}

auto foo = rank([3,6,4,2,2]);  // foo == [3, 5, 4, 1.5, 1.5]
```

The only way I can think of doing it requires allocating 3 arrays:

1. A duplicate of the input array because it has to be sorted and we don't own it.
2. An array to keep track of the order in which the input array was sorted.
3. An array of ranks to return.

Does anyone know how to do this in O(N log N) time and O(1) auxiliary space (meaning the only array we have to allocate is the one we're going to return), or at least get rid of one of the three arrays above?

Comment: What do you mean by "we don't own it"?

Comment: Actually you could probably do without the 2nd array, since lookup in a sorted array is O(log N) and you would need N lookups, which works within the O(N log N) requirement.

Comment: "we don't own it" = this is a library function that has to assume that the caller of rank() doesn't expect his input array to be gratuitously reordered, so by principle of least astonishment we have to duplicate it and sort on a copy.

Comment: You can't have O(1) auxiliary space! You have to have O(n) since the array can be variably sized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can allocate the array you are going to return (let's call it R), initialize it to 0..n-1 and then "sort" the incoming array (called I) but using the comparison I[R[k]] vs. I[R[j]] instead of the normal R[k] vs. R[j] and then swapping the values in the R array as needed (instead of the values in the I array as usual).

You can implement this indirect sorting using either quicksort or heapsort (or bubblesort but that will mess up your complexity).

You only need to allocate one array - and some stack space for the indices.

Comment: So obvious in hindsight.  Why didn't I think of this?

Comment: Actually, on second thought, this doesn't work.  I initially misunderstood it.

Comment: Yes it does - you need to compare indirectly and then update the indirecting array as well.  I have added a clarification to my post.

Comment: It works pretty well, apart for the 'average' requirement. You may need a second pass for it at the end.

Comment: Matthieu: can you explain <<the 'average' requirement>>?

Comment: Exactly the answer I was going to give. Here's an example implementation in Python: ranks = sort(range(len(l)), key=lambda x:l[x])

Comment: How does this technique solve problem of duplicates ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so you duplicate your input array into `foo`. Sort `foo` in-place in O(n log n) time with [heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort). Now, take the first element of your input array and find its rank in `foo` in O(log n) time using [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) and insert the rank into the `ranks` array and return it.

Now, you use 2 arrays instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't own the array I don't think it's possible to do it in O(N log N) and in space O(1).

If the range of elements (how large an element can be) is small, use counting. Count how many are there of each element and then calculate the result array based on the input array using the counting array.

```
c - is counting result,
C - is cumulative counting
C[i] = c[i] + c[i-1] + c[i-2] + ... + c[0]
result[i] = 1 / c[in[i]] + C[in[i]-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just copy and sort the array and go from there? There are plenty of in-place sort algorithms available such as heapsort.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be useful to summarize [florin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674307/efficiently-finding-the-ranks-of-elements-in-an-array/1674598#1674598) (and the associated comments) with some simple code.

Here's how to do it in Ruby:

```
arr = [5,1,0,3,2,4]
ranks = (0..arr.length-1).to_a.sort_by{ |x| arr[x] }
# ranks => [2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 0]
```

And in Python:

```
arr = [5,1,0,3,2,4]
ranks = range(len(arr))
ranks.sort(key=lambda x:arr[x])
# ranks => [2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 0]
```

The ranks array tells you that 0 has rank 2, 1 has rank 1, 2 has rank 4, etc.  (Of course, those ranks start at zero, not one.)

Comment: This method doesn't work for negative elements in the array: try with arr = [5,1,0,3,-2,4] -- you get [4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 0]

Answer (score 0):

How about using a Binary search tree and inserting elements one by one into that BST. Rank can then be determined by keeping a counter on all the elemtns appearing left of the element node we want to find rank of using In order Traversal of BST.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this for doing it quick and dirty in python:

```
def rank(X):
    B = X[:]
    B.sort()
    return [ float(B.index(x)+1) for x in X]

def rank(X):
    B = X[:]
    B = list(set(B))
    B.sort()
    return [ float(B.index(x)+1) for x in X]
```

First example would work in the case you don't have duplicates in your original list. It can be done better, but I was playing with some hacks and came out with this. Second one would work if you have duplicates.